# Seeking help with a MT design pattern

Tags: multithreading

I have a queue of 1000 work items and a n-proc machine (assume n = 
4).The main thread spawns n (=4)  worker threads at a time ( 25 outer 
iterations) and waits for all threads to complete before processing 
the next n (=4) items until the entire queue is processed

```
for(i= 0 to queue.Length / numprocs) 
        for(j= 0 to numprocs) 
        { 


                CreateThread(WorkerThread,WorkItem) 


        } 
        WaitForMultipleObjects(threadHandle[])
```

The work done by each (worker) thread is not homogeneous.Therefore in 
1 batch (of n) if thread 1 spends 1000 s doing work and rest of the 3 
threads only 1 s , above design is inefficient,becaue after 1 sec 
other 3 processors are idling. Besides there is no pooling - 1000 
distinct threads are being created

How do I use the NT thread pool (I am not familiar enough- hence the 
long winded question)  and QueueUserWorkitem to achieve the above. The 
following constraints should hold

1. The main thread requires that all worker items are processed before 
   it can proceed.So I would think that  a waitall like construct above 
   is required
2. I want to create as many threads as processors (ie not 1000 threads 
   at a time)
3. Also I dont want to create 1000 distinct events, pass to the worker 
   thread, and wait on all events using the QueueUserWorkitem API or 
   otherwise
4. Exisitng code is in C++.Prefer C++ because I dont know c#

I suspect that the above is a very common pattern and was looking for 
input from you folks.

Comment: "Also I dont want to create 1000 distinct events, pass to the worker thread, and wait on all events using the QueueUserWorkitem API or otherwise" --- why not? Seems like a reasonable approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C++ programmer, so I'll give you some half-way pseudo code for it

```
tcount = 0
maxproc = 4
while queue_item = queue.get_next() # depends on implementation of queue
                                    # may well be: 
                                    # for i=0; i<queue.length; i++
    while tcount == maxproc
        wait 0.1 seconds # or some other interval that isn't as cpu intensive 
                         # as continously running the loop
    tcount += 1 # must be atomic (reading the value and writing the new 
                # one must happen consecutively without interruption from 
                # other threads). I think ++tcount would handle that in cpp.
    new thread(worker, queue_item)

function worker(item)
    # ...do stuff with item here...
    tcount -= 1 # must be atomic
```

Comment: Actually it's just about as effective as you can get it. It limits it to 4 worker threads, and it executes the next item within the given wait time as soon as any thread becomes available. The only thing is that the worker thread has to handle an external variable, which may break a few "nice conventions", but just comment it to make it clear, and it's a nice efficient "hack".